# Apple says they may reject apps that are "...are simply web sites bundled as Apps..."

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview

Apple says they may reject apps that are "...are simply web sites bundled as Apps..." I am wondering why does it provide UIWebView then? If there is a mobile friendly website and UIWebView can be used to view the website within an app then why would they reject it? Does anyone have any experience with this kind of app?

Comment: Note *"simply"*; if **all** the app does is wrap a website in a `UIWebView`, what's the point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UIWebview and WKWebView classes are available for us to show SOME web content within our apps.

Take Facebook or Twitter for example. Tapping a link in either of those apps will present a webpage. This is so that users aren't thrown out of the app and sent to Safari.

Web views are also great for presenting remote or locally stored PDFs to the user.

What Apple DOESN'T want is people to come along and just wrap up their entire website and put it on the store as an app.

Many reasons include:

- Bad user experience. (e.g. Mouse hover doesn't work, its slower)
- No control over content. (whats to stop people from going to a completly different website within your app?)
- Review Process (Since web content can change anytime, apple can't really ensure your app is appropriate for the store)

Comment: That makes clear sense now. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: If it helped you please mark it as answered